# WP Mail SMTP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, server

I use WP-Mail-SMTP plugin in WordPress and I added gmail email but when I send a Test Email , it gives me 500 internal server error.
note: I'm using the last version of WordPress

Internal Server Error

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@mywebsite.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: *More information about this error may be available in the server error log.* << Have you looked in the error log?

Comment: do u mean error log file in the server?

Comment: Yes, the apache error log. If you're on shared hosting (like a cpanel) account it will be something like `error_log`

Comment: i checked it and all errors about woocommerce , i deactivated the woocommerce plugin and tested Email again and i have the same problem :(

Answer (score -1):

Please update plugin of WP Mail SMTP and version of 2.5.0. solve some bugs in new version